# Calculate time difference between NOW() and a calculated time

Tags: excel-formula

I have a cell that simply looks like `4:11 PM`.  Here is the formula that calculates it:

```
[Time In]+((TIME(8,0,0)-(K11/24))+([Lunch End]-[Lunch Start]))
```

I can go into that in more detail, but hopefully it's not necessary.

Now, what I want to do is display what is essentially a countdown, the difference between `NOW()` and `4:11 PM`.  Here is the closest I came:

`=HOUR(NOW())-HOUR(Table1[@[Leave At]])&":"&TEXT(MINUTE(NOW())-MINUTE(Table1[@[Leave At]]),"00")`

This was right until the minutes passed the comparison minutes, then it started counting back up (IE at 2:05 it said 2:06 left, but once it was 2:25 it said 2:14 left).  Sorry if this is not clear.

One of the problems is, if I try `TIMEVALUE(L12)` (L12 being 4:11 PM) I get `#VALUE!`.  I'm assuming this is why it's not working, and why simply doing `=L12-NOW()` didn't work.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try this `=L12-TIME(HOUR(NOW()),MINUTE(NOW()),0)`.

Comment: So far that looks accurate!  Please post as answer and I'll accept after I'm sure :)

Comment: Be Advised that now only calculates when the worksheet calculates.  Meaning that if you have automatic updates on it will change everything a value is entered in a cell.  however the instant you stop entering items, the spreadsheet will stop calculating so you will not get a CONTINUOUS real time feed back.  You can stare at your worksheet all day and nothing will happen.  (Unless you have some other code somewhere that is causing it to recalculate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is NOW() is a DATE/TIME so the numeric value is >42000.  Wand when subtracting it from A time which is <0 you get a negative number, so NOW() needs to be changed to just its decimal part:

```
=L12-TIME(HOUR(NOW()),MINUTE(NOW()),0)
```

Or

```
=L12-(NOW()-INT(NOW()))
```

The second will return seconds with the output.